# php file search issue - not returning full path to file

Tags: php, file, search

This script will search my server for files starting by a specific string, then return the download links. Search query is defined by "f" GET value.

Now let's say that i have the following files on my server:

> /folder/example file number one.zip 
>   /folder/example file number two.zip
>   /folder/example file number three.zip

If i search for "example file" then the script will return 3 results BUT every download links will be "/folder/example file" instead of the FULL filename (/folder/example file number XXX.zip).

This will also create a bug with the filesize() function at the end of the script, since filesize() will look for the size of "/folder/example file" instead of using the full filename

Can you help me to fix that ?

```
$request = $_GET['f'];
$adr = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
$decode = rawurldecode(substr($adr, 2));

echo "Searching for $decode";

// finding the file on the server
$root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$search = preg_quote(utf8_decode($decode));

function rsearch($folder, $pattern) {
    $dir = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($folder);
    $ite = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir);
    $files = new RegexIterator($ite, $pattern, RegexIterator::GET_MATCH);
    $fileList = array();
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        $fileList = array_merge($fileList, $file);
    }
    return $fileList;
}
$resultatss = rsearch($root, '/.*\/'.$search.'/');

foreach ($resultatss as $resultat) {
    $downloadlink = str_replace("$root/", "", $resultat);
    $pos = strrpos($downloadlink, '/') + 1;
    $encodedownloadlink = substr($downloadlink, 0, $pos) . rawurlencode(substr($downloadlink, $pos));

    if (!empty($downloadlink)) {
        echo "download link = http://www.mydomain.com/$encodedownloadlink";
        $taillekb = filesize($downloadlink) / 1024;
        echo "<br>Size: $taillekb KB<br>";
    } else {
        echo "File not found";
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was unfamiliar with the `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` function, so I decided to check it out. Neat stuff! I wrote the following, it seems to do what you want:

**Method #1 ...**

```
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$search = rawurldecode($_GET['f']);

$it = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator( $path );
foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($it) as $file){
    $pathfile = str_replace($path,'',$file);
    if (strpos($pathfile, $search) !== false) {
        echo 'file = '. basename($file) .'<br>';
        echo 'link = http://www.mydomain.com'. $pathfile .'<br>';
        echo 'size = '. round(filesize($file)/1024,2) .' KB<br><br>';
    }
}
```

You run it via `http://www.mydomain.com/search.php?f=whatever` ... assuming you name the script `search.php`, this will find any file containing the word `whatever`.

**Method #2 ...**

If you want to split this apart (putting the search in a function), here's how that looks:

```
function rsearch($path, $search) {
    $files = array();
    $it = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator( $path );
    foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($it) as $file){
        if (strpos($file, $search) !== false) $files[] = $file;
    }
    return $files;
}

$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$search = rawurldecode($_GET['f']);

$files = rsearch($path, $search);

foreach ($files as $file) {
    $pathfile = str_replace($path,'',$file);
    if (strpos($pathfile, $search) !== false) {
        echo 'file = '. basename($file) .'<br>';
        echo 'link = http://www.mydomain.com'. $pathfile .'<br>';
        echo 'size = '. round(filesize($file)/1024,2) .' KB<br><br>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Same problem... This part of the script is just to remove the folders in the URL and keep only the file name. By changing it with your code, the script will return the folder name before the filename but i still get an incomplete filename when i search for only the first words

Comment: Hmm.. I'm unfamiliar with the `rsearch()` function, what is that doing?

Comment: check my post, i have posted the code of the function. It is a RecursiveDirectoryIterator that will search all folders and sub-folders for a string, then return the list of the files found. Problem is that the filenames are incomplete, the script just returns the search query when a file is found